# Reflections along root vectors in a basis generate the Weyl group?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, integer-lattices, root-systems

Let $\Phi$ be a root system of type ADE, $\Lambda$ be the lattice in the Euclidean space spanned by $\Phi$. If $\Lambda$ is spanned by $\{v_i\}\subset \Phi$ (as a $\mathbb Z$-module), and let $\sigma_i$ be the reflection along hyperplane associated to $v_i$. Is it true that $\{\sigma_i\}$ generate the Weyl group $W(\Phi)$?

---

**My approach**

I know there is a proposition says reflections along vectors in a base (of a root system, or in some book called simple system) generate the full $W(\Phi)$. So I tried to show $\{v_i\}$ contains a base, but have no idea how to do this. More precisely, I don't know how to use the condition $\{v_i\}$ generate $\Lambda$.

---

If this too general, what about the case $\Phi=E_6$? If $6$ vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_6$ in the root system generate the lattice, is it true that after possibally replacing $v_i$ by $-v_i$ for some $i$, they will form a base of $E_6$?

Comment: A root system should appear somehow, "spanned by $\{v_i\}$..." is too general, this comment tries to be shorter than the question, not so simple...

Comment: @dan_fulea Yes you are right, otherwise there are trivial counter-examples. I added some conditions.

Comment: Why the restriction to types ADE? Do you have counterexamples for the other cases -- maybe they are worth a look.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Because otherwise there will be trivil counterexample. For example in $B_2$ the two minimal vectors form a basis of the lattice but did not generate the Weyl group.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Phi'$ be the root subsystem of $\Phi$ generated by $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ where $n$ is the rank of $\Phi$. Then, $\Phi'$ itself also has rank $n$ (because the $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly independent). Because $\Phi$ is simply laced, it follows that $\Phi=\Phi'$. Indeed, the Dynkin diagram of $\Phi'$ is a subdiagram of the one of $\Phi$ (each time with respect to some base) and both have $n$ vertices. Since there are only simple edges, we conclude that the diagrams are equal. It follows that $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ form a base up to sign. By replacing $v_i$ with $-v_i$ if necessary, which does not change the reflection along $v_i$, we may assume that $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ form a base of $\Phi$. Hence, $s_{v_1},\ldots,s_{v_n}$ generate $W$.

Comment: What is $v_i$? Is it the same as $v_i$ in the question setting?

Comment: Yes, the $v_i$'s are in $\Phi$ and span $\Lambda$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module - as in the question.

Comment: Then how do you pick $n$ of them?

Comment: $n$ is the rank of the lattice $\Lambda$. If $v_i$ span the lattice, there must be at least $n$ of them (invariant basis number for commutative rings). If there are more, you can pick $n$ which form a basis.

Comment: Sorry I still cannot follow. Why $\{v_i\}$ forms a basis (I suppose you mean base, i.e. simple system) up to sign?

Comment: The $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are $n$ roots which generate the whole system $\Phi$ (because $\Phi=\Phi'$) and $n$ is the rank of $\Phi$. Therefore, you can write any root $\gamma\in\Phi$ as linear combination in $v_i$. By arranging the signs of the $v_i$, you get coefficients in $\gamma$ either totally positive or totally negative. Hence, the $v_i$'s form a base (right, I mean base here).

Comment: If you think in pictures: The $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ correspond each to one node of the Dynkin diagram. Now, you have Cartan integers by pairing $v_i$ and $v_j$ equal to $-1,0,1$. By replacing $v_i$ with $-v_i$ if necessary, you can arrange things to be like the Cartan matrix you want (of the type of $\Phi$).

Comment: I am very sorry for replying so late, but I doubt your claim that "if $n$ vectors generate the lattice, then we can arrange the signs to make them form a base". Just consider the case $\Phi=A_3$ and $a,b,c$ be a base, where $b$ is the vector has $2\pi/3$ angles with both $a$ and $b$. Then if you consider $\{a,b,a+b+c\}$, it still generates the lattice, but there is no way to make it a base by simply arranging the signs.

Comment: In your example, let $a'=-a$, $b'=-b$, $c'=a+b+c$. Then, $a',b',c'$ form a base of $\Phi$, as well as $-a',-b',-c'$. Indeed, write out the whole $\Phi$ and express each of the vectors in terms of $a',b',c'$. You will see that all coefficients have the same sign, here $\pm 1$. The Dynkin diagram is $c'-a'-b'$.

Comment: Sorry, there is some typo in my last comment. Consider the Dynkin diagram $a-b-c$ and $\{a,a+b,a+b+c\}$. Then there is no way to make it a base by arranging the signs.

Comment: You are right this time. I agree with you. But the group generated by the reflections along $a,a+b,a+b+c$ is still $S_4$. I can delete my answer if you wish.

Comment: What you see from this example, however, the $\mathbb{Z}$-linear transformations you peform on the basis of the root lattice to reach a base reflect precisely the braid relations you need to reach the reflections along the base in the Weyl group - because there are only three-term braid relations in the simply laced case which correspond each time to one subtraction/addition.

Comment: Yeah this case is okay. But I want to know how to do the general case. It is still a question to me.